# How to reuse a pattern found by a wildcard?

Tags: bash

I want to convert all `.swf` files to `mp4` files in a certain directory. I use a `*` wildcard to identify all files ending with `.swf` in the folder -> `*.swf`.
So, let's say that I have several videos:

- video1.swf
- video2.swf

I want to reuse the found name in the new naming, here `video1.mp4` and `video2.mp4` on my bash example:

```
ffmpeg -i *.swf -vcodec mpeg4 *.mp4
```

**How to reuse a pattern found by a wildcard?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use loop for each filename in the pattern, and replace the file extension:

```
for f in *.swf ; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec mpeg4  "$(basename "$f" .swf).mp4" ; done
```

Comment: I use `basename` a lot too, but in Bash it might be better to use `"${f%.swf}.mp4"` as it avoids running a separate program.

Answer (score 5):

You can use BASH string replacement:

```
s='video1.swf'
f="${s/.swf/.mp4}"
echo "$f"
video1.mp4
```

Using `ffmpeg`:

```
for f in *.swf; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec mpeg4 "${f%.swf}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: It might be better to use `"${f%.swf}.mp4"` as it avoids substitutions in the middle of a name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes it is unlikely scenario but still possible (edited)

Answer (score 3):

You can populate an array with the file names:

```
files=(*.swf)
```

Then, do a replacement on the whole array to get the new names:

```
ffmpeg -i "${files[@]}" -vcodec mpeg4 "${files[@]/%.swf/.mp4}"
```

Comment: Don't you need to prefix *each* input file with `-i`? `ffmpeg "${files[@]/#/-i }" ...` (I've never used `ffmpeg`, but that's how I read the man page; just confirming before I up vote.)

Comment: @chepner: I haven't used it either. Just trying to simulate the line given by Jon in the question.

Comment: +1, as this only requires a single call to `ffmpeg`. Between the answer and my comment, anyone trying to use it should be able to get the correct syntax :)